# Problems loading/using jsoup in ColdBox/Lucee

Tags: coldfusion, jsoup

there are many posts on issues similar to mine, but none of them has helped. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to load the jsoup jar using this.applicationSettings, and I keep getting an error. Specifically:

Application.cfc:

```
this.javaSettings = { 
    loadPaths = [ ".\lib" ], 
    loadColdFusionClassPath = true, 
    reloadOnChange= false 
};
```

Yes, jsoup-1.11.2.jar is in \lib for that application. I tried \lib\ too; no joy.

But every time I try to use

```
myJsoup = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup");
```

or

```
myJsoup = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup").init();
```

I get an error,

```
cannot load class through its string name, because no definition for the class with the specified name [org.jsoup.Jsoup] could be found
```

Does not matter what function I place the init code in -- handler or model -- or if I put it in a cfscript or cfset. I can even put it in index.cfm and still get the same error. Does not matter what I restart or how many times I restart it. It is as if ColdBox and/or Lucee just refuses to acknowledge the existence of the jar file or something. What gives?

I sure would appreciate any tips! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you dumped/logged what's being returned in `this.javaSettings` to confirm that it is indeed finding the path you're specifying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is just bad documentation out in the wild, a shortcoming of my own understanding or simply a bug in ColdFusion and Lucee...

I put together a simple test and recreated what you're seeing in both engines. I originally figured there must be an issue with paths in Lucee but ACF produces the same error.

Looking at existing code I use, it seems I always populate the full path to the JAR/Class files.

I often do something like this (which works) to load everything in the `/lib` directory:

`this.javaSettings.loadPaths = directoryList(expandPath("/lib"));`

Which in turn sets the value to `[ "/mypath/lib/jsoup-1.11.2.jar" ]`.

Comment: Thanks Tony! That worked! I really appreciate it -- I had gotten pretty frustrated, I must admit. To test, I added the full path to javasettings and that worked too. Your answer will really help out in other projects too. In fact, if you do not mind, I will post a link to this thread on the ColdBox discussion board -- I think it will help some people out there, as well! Many thanks, again, Tony!

Comment: @TonyJunkes - "ACF produces the same error" I was trying to reproduce the error too, but couldn't. Where exactly were your jars,  outside the web root? My test jars were {webroot}/lib.

Comment: @Ageax, I tested everything in the webroot using CF2016 and Lucee 5 in CommandBox.

Comment: @TonyJunkes - Weird... I tried the sample code with CF11, & 2016 too, but couldn't reproduce it. Even pre-tested first with an empty ./lib and got the expected "class not found".  Oh well.. must be doing something different on my end.